# Зачем Visual Studio 2017 требует Private ReadOnly для Private свойства?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2015, vb.net

Привык работать с защищенными полями, начинающимися с _ , переехал на 2017 версию студии с 2015, и теперь она мне рекомендует добавлять ReadOnly для таких свойств.

Зачем студия требует вместо

```
Private _property As New Hashtable()
```

это

```
Private ReadOnly _property As New Hashtable()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для приватных полей компилятор проверяет, изменяются ли они где-нибудь после вызова конструктора. Если нет, то рекомендует явно пометить их модификатором `readonly` в `C#` или `ReadOnly` в `VB`.

Насколько мне известно, это не приводит к каким-то дополнительным оптимизациям, но позволяет явно запретить изменение поля на синтаксическом уровне, чтобы, например, избежать непонимания внутреннего контракта класса среди участников одной команды.

[А тут можно почитать на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277010/what-are-the-benefits-to-marking-a-field-as-readonly-in-c)

Проверил поведение на Visual Studio 2017 и 2019, и там есть разница. В VS2017 при вызове каких-либо методов/свойств изменяемого объекта сообщение, предлагающее добавить модификатор `readonly`/`ReadOnly`, пропадает. Я так полагаю, это сделано для того, чтобы не вводить разработчика в заблуждение модификатором 'только для чтения', который не запрещает изменение экземпляра объекта, а только лишь препятствует изменению самой ссылки на объект. В VS2019 сообщение присутствует вне зависимости от наличия последующих вызовов методов/свойств, по принципу, который я описал выше. По-видимому, в VS2019 доработали анализатор кода.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Боюсь к конструктору это ни какого отношения не имеет, ели есть методы в которых идет работа с этой переменной, включая вызовы методов если это объект, то рекомендация не показывается.

Comment: Я немного не это имел в виду. Каждое поле/приватное свойство вы либо изменяете после вызова конструктора (в других методах), либо нет. Если изменяете, у компилятора нет к вам никаких вопросов. Если же вдруг значение поля/свойства нигде не меняется, компилятор предполагает, что оно и не должно меняться, и предлагает указать это явно с помощью модификатора ReadOnly, чтобы в дальнейшем никто необдуманно не изменил это значение.

Comment: Например, если у вас в качестве поля/приватного свойства выступает `List<T>`, и вы нигде не меняете значение поля, работая исключительно с методами самого объекта `List<T>`, то есть смысл пометить его как `readonly`, чтобы кто-нибудь из членов вашей команды не решил очищать этот список с помощью `list = new List<T>();` вместо `list.Clear();` и не вызвал тем самым лишней нагрузки на сборщик мусора. Это первый пример, который пришел в голову.

Comment: В том то и дело что нет разницы, присваивание или вызов метода. https://c2n.me/460d5ru    https://clip2net.com/s/460dddi

Comment: А вот это, на самом деле, уже интересно. Приеду домой, посмотрю.

Comment: Проверил, обновил ответ.